# How to enter data into a text area and click on search button

Tags: vba

I am trying to fill the text area and click on search button on a web tool. I wrote the below code but it just opens up the tool. However , does not fill up the text area.

Below is my code:

```
Sub PLCbot()
Dim myvalue As String
Dim myie As Object
Dim myloop As Object
Dim myelements As Object
Dim wksheet As Worksheet
Dim Workbook As Workbook

myvalue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Set myie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
myie.Visible = True
myie.Navigate2 "http://psrhpinc.usa.hp.com/wplc/SalesMarketingView.aspx?ViewOption=SalesMarket"
Do While myie.Busy
Loop

Set myelements = myie.document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
For Each myloop In myelements
If myloop.Name = "textarea" Then

myloop.Value = myvalue
End If
Exit For
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exit For` should be inside If-End If. Try below

```
For Each myloop In myelements
    If myloop.Name = "textarea" Then
        myloop.Value = myvalue
        Exit For
    End If  
Next
```

Comment: Hi mukul. Thanks for your suggestion. However , I am still not able to view anything on the text area.

Comment: ok. Did you debug it ? Put a break point on the for loop and end sub. Check if tag you are searching (i.e. textarea) is there in myelements. I doubt the condition is incorrect. tag name is textarea and you need to search for id or name or some attribute to identify your requirement.